# Locker Service and passing the response from a server action into another namespace

Tags: managed-package, locker-service

For a little while, I've been using a generic Lightning component with an `aura:method` to handle server responses. It looks at `response.getState()` to see if there are any errors, and can then display them as toasts or ui:messages. It's declared like this:

```
<aura:method name="handleResponse" action="{!c.handleResponse}" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="response" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="successHandler" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="errorHandler" type="Object" />
</aura:method>
```

The start of the method (in a helper, so the params are already split out) is like this:

```
handleResponse : function(component, response, successHandler, errorHandler) {
    var state = response.getState();

    if(state === 'SUCCESS') {
        if(!$A.util.isEmpty(successHandler)) {
            successHandler(response);
        }
    } else {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

It's used like this:

```
var errorHandler = component.find('errorHandler');
serverAction.setCallback(this, function(response){
    errorHandler.handleResponse(response,
        function(successResponse) {
            // Things to do on success
        }
    );
});
```

Recently, I put that component into a package (with Packaging 2, probably not relevant to the problem).

Now that the component is in its own package (i.e. its own namespace), I'm finding that Locker Service has stripped everything out of the response object by the time it reaches the `handleResponse`. However, the `successHandler` still works.

I've verified this by stopping it in the browser's debugger, and replacing `var state = response.getState()` by just `var state = 'SUCCESS'`. When I do that, the `successHandler` is run and works as expected. The response object, though, is just an empty-ish object described by the console as `{toString: ƒ}`.

It's going to be really tedious to experiment with this by creating many package versions to test it. Can someone let me know what Locker Service is doing with `response` and why? I could, for example, pull out `response.getState()` and pass that string directly. But my component also needs to call `response.getError()`... if I pass that separately, is it just going to get swallowed up by Locker Service again?

**Edit**

This workaround does the job (and doesn't require modifying the package), but it's pretty dodgy:

```
var errorHandler = component.find('errorHandler');
serverAction.setCallback(this, function(response){
    errorHandler.handleResponse(
        {
            getState : function() { return response.getState();},
            getError : function() { return response.getError();}
        },
        function(successResponse) {
            // Things to do on success
        }
    );
});
```